# Remote process communication

Tags: unix, rpc

How can I do inter-process communication between two remote process on unix C/C++? Currently,  popen works for  two process on same host? Product need to be capability to call remote process and send /receive the data.

Comment: IPC != RPC, fix the tags once you know what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned `popen` you may not realize this already allows you to use `ssh` to remotely execute a process and treat exactly the same as a locally spawned one.

```
popen ("ssh user@remotehost /usr/bin/cal", "r")
```

And a pre-emptive link for further questions on `ssh`:

https://serverfault.com/questions/117007/ssh-key-questions

Answer (score 0):

why would you nut just open the wild card % in the IP so that they could access the host.. remorely..

192.168.1.% something like that...:D